# Send form with empty input in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I started my studies with Angularjs a few days ago.
Look my code below, I have two forms. When I send my first form with empty inputs, it´s OK. In my second form, if a send the same way it´s not OK, 
but in my second if I write something clean, then it's working. This happened just in the first click. My error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name2' of undefined     at ChildScope.$scope.enviar2
```

How can I resolve this?

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('Controller', function($scope){

        $scope.send1 = function() {
            console.log("NAME: " + $scope.name1);
            console.log("AGE:" + $scope.age1);
        };

        $scope.send2 = function(opcao) {
            console.log("NAME: " + $scope.option.name2);
            console.log("AGE: " + $scope.option.age2);
        };
    });
```

Filter 1

```
ng-model="name1"
ng-model="age1"
ng-submit="send1();
```

Filter 2

```
ng-model="option.name1"
ng-model="option.age1"
ng-submit="send2(option);
```

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

**Some code correction need to be made :**

- As `send2(option)` function containing the `option object` then we can directly access the properties of the object with `.` operator inside the function instead of using `$scope` object.
- As option object does not contain any property with `name2` & `age2` but we are trying to access then we will get `undefined` only as these properties does not exist.

**Working demo :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.send1 = function() {
      console.log("NAME: " + $scope.name1);
      console.log("AGE:" + $scope.age1);
    };

    $scope.send2 = function(opcao) {
      console.log("NAME: " + opcao.name1);
      console.log("AGE: " + opcao.age1);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name1"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="age1"/>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="send1();">Form 1</button>
  </form><br>
    <form>
  <input type="text" ng-model="option.name1"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="option.age1"/>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="send2(option);">Form 2</button>
  </form>
</div>
```